# how to update all keys with the same name in a array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I am using react and redux and would like to decrement each 'volume' key value by a random number between 0 and 20 (both included) then update the state array.

my array is such:

```
const arr = [
  {id: 1, volume: 100, isEmpty: false},
  {id: 2, volume: 100, isEmpty: false}
]
```

this is my action:

```
const decrementAction = () => {
    return {
        type : 'DECREMENT'
    }
}
```

my reducer is such:

```
const containers = (state = arr, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'DECREMENT':
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 0;
      const newArr = arr.map(item => {
        const newObj = {
          ...item,
          volume : item.volume - randomNumber
        }
        return newObj;
      });
      state = newArray
  }
};
```

I am having a couple of issues when running my code:

1 - each value is the same as opposed to getting a random value for each object (solved)

2 - the values are both incremented and decremented as opposed to only being decremented

please, what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution...

instead of

```
const containers = (state = arr, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'DECREMENT':
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 0;
      const newArr = arr.map(item => {
        const newObj = {
          ...item,
          volume : item.volume - randomNumber
        }
        return newObj;
      });
      state = newArray
  }
};
```

line 5 I referred to the state as 'arr' but I should have referred to the state as 'state' as shown below.

```
const containers = (state = arr, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'DECREMENT':
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 0;
      const newArr = state.map(item => {
        const newObj = {
          ...item,
          volume : item.volume - randomNumber
        }
        return newObj;
      });
      state = newArray
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you are getting the random number only once. You need a new random number every time.

Try to run the whole thing in a loop and keep adding items by destructuring them as you are doing currently.

```
const containers = (state = arr, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'DECREMENT':
      let newArr = [];
      for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 0;
       const newObj = {
          ...arr[i],
          volume : arr[i].volume - randomNumber
        };
      newArr.push(newObj);
      }
      return newArr;
      break;
   
   }
};
```

Also I believe with redux you are supposed to return the state.

Comment: thank you, you were right about randomNumber!

Comment: No issues. If this solves your issue, please use green tick to accept the answer

Comment: my issue is only partially solved, hence why I've not used the green tick

Comment: Ok. Please let me know what is not working currently

Comment: sure, each time my action is dispatched the value changes but instead of it being reduced all time, the random number is either added or subtracted. Ultimately the aim is to bring the volume value down to 0

Comment: Strange for that to happen. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example. Or maybe more of your code

Comment: iteration 1 volume : 100, iteration 2 volume : 98, iteration 3 volume : 90, iteration 4 volume : 101

Comment: Just changed the code. `item` was a mistake. I hope you are using `arr[i]`. If this does not solve it, you can add a min. repro example

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting a `break;` after `state = newArray` in your reducer, that should at least resolve your second issue:

```
 const containers = (state = arr, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'DECREMENT':
      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 0;
      const newArr = arr.map(item => {
        const newObj = {
          ...item,
          volume : item.volume - randomNumber
        }
        return newObj;
      });
      state = newArray;
      break;
  }
};
```

Javascript switch reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: thank you, I have tried with your recommendation but it hasn't resolved my issue.